# Navigation Controller (How to free memory when i press button "back")

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

Hello all :) i have question about a "navigation controller" i have structure 
INIT-> Navigation Controller -> View Controller (use Table View for output data from data) -> View Controller (go to from the selected cell and display data).
I looked at the performance of the application and noticed that when i press button "back" and click at something data in table view and open again new view controller, Memory is increasing every time when i want look at data (i mean make a new view controller).
The question: How to free memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you click back button the secondVC is automatically deallocated and you can verify that by logging in

```
deinit{
  print("VC deallocated")
}
```

but this happens only if you don't have a strong reference to `self` and this occurs if you reference self inside a completion block , the view controller is being strongly referenced by some outside object or have a timer that you forget to invalidate when clicking back and many other cases